# How to alias namespaces in a codeigniter application?

Tags: php, codeigniter, eloquent, composer-php

I have a codeigniter which I integrated composer into. I'm following a tutorial to implement Laravel's Eloquent orm into my application which is working great. My question is in Laravel, you can simply do :

```
class User extends Eloquent {
}
```

to use your model but for my implemantion I have to do

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
class User extends Eloquent {
}
```

How would I alias across all my models in codeigniter?

Comment: "I have to do" Err......why do you have to do that? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

There is a core php method called `class_alias`. It allows you to Alias frequently used classes with a shorter name, mostly used to remove a long namespace.

More information on:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php

This is how Laravel uses it: it uses a custom class AliasLoader that runs over every item in the alias array of the configuration and calls `class_alias` for it.

See:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8b9bdc869ca7995412b10568122c496be244430a/src/Illuminate/Foundation/AliasLoader.php#L64